# How to clear objects created in rspec test suite?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an application which runs only on ruby with no external libraries/gems
I do have rspec as testing framework. I need to know if there is a way to clear/destroy class objects created during the execution of rspec tests,  since objects created by tests is making some other tests fail

Thanks in advance

Comment: What "class objects" do you mean exactly? Database records? Actual classes? Show a [mcve]

Comment: I dont have a db and active_record, when I say objects its just ClassName.new

Comment: Okay, definitely will need the mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [before and after hooks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks) in RSpec to clean up after yourself. Also, try to make use of [mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs) wherever possible to keep things clean.